# scrapy not working on imdb keywords pages

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Here is how I intend this code to work;
I have a keyword, say, "gadgets". I search titles on advanced imdb search page. I want the code to go to each title page, then go to keywords page of each title and then download title and all the keywords.
The code structure looks good to me but it is really not working.
Please suggest whether it needs to be re-written or it can be corrected with some advice?

Here is my spider:

```
import scrapy

class KwordsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name= 'ImdbSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['imdb.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?keywords=gadgets'
    ]    
    def parse(self, response):
        titleLinks = response.xpath('//*[@class="lister-item-content"]')

        for link in titleLinks:
            title_url = 'https://www.imdb.com'+link.xpath('.//h3/a/@href').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(title_url, callback=self.parse_title)
        next_page_url = 'https://www.imdb.com'+response.xpath('//div[@class="article"]/div[@class="desc"]/a[@href]').extract_first()
        if next_page_url is not None:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse) 

    def parse_title(self, response):
        keywords_url = 'https://www.imdb.com' + response.xpath('//nobr/a[@href]').extract_first()

        yield scrapy.Request(keywords_url, callback=self.parse_keys)
    #looking at the keywords page
    def parse_keys(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//h3/a/text()').extract_first()
        keys = response.xpath('//div[@class="sodatext"]/a/text()').extract()
        print('my print'+title)    
        yield{
            'title': title,
            'Keywords': keys,
        }
```

Following are few power shell lines

```
2020-05-02 08:33:40 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-05-02 08:33:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-05-02 08:33:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-05-02 08:33:40 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-05-02 08:33:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?keywords=gadgets> (referer: None)
2020-05-02 08:33:43 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.imdb.com<a href="': <GET https://www.imdb.com<a href="/search/title/?keywords=gadgets&amp;start=51%22%20class=%22lister-page-next%20next-page%22%3ENext%20%C2%BB%3C/a%3E>
2020-05-02 08:33:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3896198/> (referer: https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?keywords=gadgets)
2020-05-02 08:34:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0369171/> (referer: https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?keywords=gadgets)
2020-05-02 08:34:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1149317/> (referer: https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?keywords=gadgets)
2020-05-02 08:34:11 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few xpaths in your script were wrong. I've fixed them. It should work now.

```
class KwordsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ImdbSpider'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?keywords=gadgets'
    ]    
    def parse(self, response):
        titleLinks = response.xpath('//*[@class="lister-item-content"]')

        for link in titleLinks:
            title_url = response.urljoin(link.xpath('.//h3/a/@href').get())
            yield scrapy.Request(title_url, callback=self.parse_title)

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//div[@class="article"]/div[@class="desc"]/a/@href').get()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse) 

    def parse_title(self, response):
        keywords_url = response.urljoin(response.xpath('//nobr/a/@href').get())
        yield scrapy.Request(keywords_url, callback=self.parse_keys)

    def parse_keys(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//h3/a/text()').get()
        keys = response.xpath('//div[@class="sodatext"]/a/text()').getall()
        yield {
            'title': title,
            'Keywords': keys,
        }
```

Comment: One thing I am confused, I am trying to get title_url in yield {
            'title': title, 'Link': 'title_url',
            'Keywords': keys,
        } but it is not working. How can it be done.

Comment: I'm not sure I could understand your problem. I can see `title_url` in `parse()` method. Do you wanna print it in `parse_keys()` method? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Yes I wanted that. I used meta and I was able to transfer variable method to method.